# RSpec `should_receive` behaviour with multiple method invocation

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rspec2

Consider the following test:

```
class A
  def print(args)
    puts args
  end
end

describe A do
  let(:a) {A.new}

  it "receives print" do
   a.should_receive(:print).with("World").and_call_original

   a.print("Hello")
   a.print("World")
 end
end
```

The [RSpec Documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message!) says:

> Use should_receive() to set an expectation that a receiver should receive a
>   message before the example is completed.

So I was expecting this test to pass, but it is not. It is failing with the following message:

```
Failures:

1) A receives print
 Failure/Error: a.print("Hello")
   #<A:0x007feb46283190> received :print with unexpected arguments
     expected: ("World")
          got: ("Hello")
```

Is this expected behaviour? Is there a way to make this test pass?

I am using **ruby 1.9.3p374** and **rspec 2.13.1**

Comment: What documentation you are following? would you share link ? This is I am asking for my self study... :))

Comment: There is a link in the question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
class A
  def print(args)
    puts args
  end
end

describe A do
  let(:a) {A.new}

  it "receives print" do
   a.stub(:print).with(anything())
   a.should_receive(:print).with("World").and_call_original

   a.print("Hello")
   a.print("World")
 end
end
```

The test was failing because you had set a precise expectation "a should receive :print with 'World'", but rspec noticed that the a object was receiving the `print` method with 'Hello' therefore it failed the test. In my solution, I allow the `print` method to be invoked with any argument, but it still keeps track of the call with "World" as argument.

Comment: In this example, if you omit the `a.print("World")` line, it will fail?

Comment: @vrinek Yep, it does with `Failure/Error: a.should_receive(:print).with("World").and_call_original #<A:0x007feec13ae2a8> received :print with unexpected arguments`

Comment: I think `a.stub(:print).with(anything).and_call_original` would be better

Comment: Oh sure, it depends if that method call is a query or a command :)

Answer (score 4):

How about adding `allow(a).to receive(:print)`?

```
require 'rspec'

class A
  def print(args)
    puts args
  end
end

describe A do
  let(:a) { described_class.new }

  it 'receives print' do
    allow(a).to receive(:print)
    expect(a).to receive(:print).with('World')

    a.print('Hello')
    a.print('World')
  end
end
```

Basically, `allow(a).to_receive(:print)` allows "a" to receive a "print" message with any arguments. Thus `a.print('Hello')` doesn't fail the test.

Comment: this answer fixed my problem after spending half a day can't find a solution! Thanks a million

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
class A
  def print(args)
    puts args
  end
end

describe A do
  let(:a) {A.new}

  it "receives print" do
   a.should_receive(:print).with("World").and_call_original
   # it's important that this is after the real expectation
   a.should_receive(:print).any_number_of_times

   a.print("Hello")
   a.print("World")
 end
end
```

It adds a second expectation, which you may want to avoid. However, in consideration of @vrinek's question, this solution has the advantage of providing the correct failure message (expected: 1 time, received: 0 times). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`should_receive` checks not only that the expected method was called, but that unexpected methods are *not* called. Simply add a specification for each invocation you expect:

```
class A
  def print(args)
    puts args
  end
end

describe A do
  let(:a) {A.new}

  it "receives print" do
   a.should_receive(:print).with("World").and_call_original
   a.should_receive(:print).with("Hello").and_call_original

   a.print("Hello")
   a.print("World")
 end
end
```

Comment: The problem is that this is a unit test, and I do not want to pollute it with invocations that have nothing to do with the functionality I wish to test.